# Make DIVs move to corners of page when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have four DIVs to divide the page into four parts:

1. top-left
2. top-right
3. bottom-left
4. bottom-right

Now I want to create an animation using jQuery that triggers on button click, so that if user clicks, all four divs fade-out of the page, and to their respective corners like:

- top-left div fades out to top-left corner of page
- top-right fades out top-right and so on

I've found the `explode` method in jQuery but it's different from what I want.

Here is an image:

[image]

So if someone click the button, all four divs fade out to the corners of the page and, if clicked again reappear in their original position.

Here is what I do:

**HTML**

```
<div class="animate" style="float:left;">some text here</div>
<div class="animate" style="float:right;">some text here</div>
<div class="animate" style="top:50%; float:left;">some text here</div>
<div class="animate" style="top:50%; float:right;">some text here</div>

<button>Click here</button>
```

**JS**

```
$('button').click(function(e) {
   $(".div1").toggle( "explode" );
});
```

or

```
$('button').click(function(e) {
    $(".div1").fadeToggle(function()
    {
      $(this).animate({"left": "0","top":"0"});
    });
});
```

But they all fade out to one corner of the page. I don't know where the mistake is.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you a start.  Anchor each of the divs to its corner, then animate height, width and opacity:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('.animate').animate({'opacity' : 0,
    'height': 0,
    'width': 0
  }, 1000);
})
```

```css
.animate {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}
#topL {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#topR {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#bottomL {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#bottomR {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:200px;height:200px;position:relative;">
  <div class="animate" id="topL">some text here</div>
  <div class="animate" id="topR">some text here</div>
  <div class="animate" id="bottomL">some text here</div>
  <div class="animate" id="bottomR">some text here</div>
</div>

<button>Click here</button>
```